# Inno IDE Rename directory during copy

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I have an Inno setup script with the following line in the **[files]** section:

```
Source: Release\bin\glassfish-3.1.2; DestDir: {sd}\MyApp; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs external;
```

I want the glassfish directory to be renamed so that it is C:\MyApp when it is copied. I have tried several variations with no resolve. Must be a simple option to add on.

Comment: Also note that installing to {sd}/blah isn't recomended in favour of correctly installing into {pf}/blah

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the files and directories under the glassfish-3.1.2, you'll need to change your source to the following:

```
Source: Release\bin\glassfish-3.1.2\*; DestDir: {sd}\MyApp; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs external;
```

Comment: I made your suggested change but it still shows glassfish-3.1.2 as the folder name when it copies it. My script (without your line) can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404445/inno-ide-eliminate-view-checkbox-after-installation