# Inno IDE Eliminate View checkbox after installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

After an installation has completed, the installer gives the user a check box option labeled "View" that gives the user the option to apparently open the installation folder upon completion of the install. How do I disable this?

Once the install completes, I don't want the user to have the option to "View" anything. Just close the installer.

**UPDATE:** here is the script:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My App"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Blah, LLC"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.blah.com/"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppID={{f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
CreateAppDir=false
LicenseFile=Release\EULA.rtf
SetupIconFile=Release\bin\logo.ico
Compression=lzma/Max
SolidCompression=true
AppCopyright=Blah, LLC
AppVerName={#MyAppName}
DisableFinishedPage=yes
VersionInfoVersion=1.0
VersionInfoCompany=Blah, LLC
VersionInfoDescription=My description here.
VersionInfoCopyright=2012
VersionInfoProductName=My App
VersionInfoProductVersion=1.0

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: Release\bin\glassfish-3.1.2; DestDir: {sd}\MyApp; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs external; 
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
Source: {src}\README.txt; DestDir: {tmp}; Attribs: ReadOnly; Flags: isreadme external dontcopy;

[Types]
Name: full; Description: "Full Installation";
Name: custom; Description: "Custom Installation"; Flags: IsCustom;

[Components]
Name: webserver; Description: "GlassFish 3.1.2 Application Server"; Types: full custom; ExtraDiskSpaceRequired: 100851712; 
Name: sqlserver; Description: "SQL Server Express 2008 R2"; ExtraDiskSpaceRequired: 745537536; Types: full custom;
Name: sqlserver\sqlserver_x64; Description: "Microsoft SQL Server Express (x64)"; Flags: exclusive; Types: full custom; 
Name: sqlserver\sqlserver_x86; Description: "Microsoft SQL Server Express (x86)"; Flags: exclusive; Types: full custom;

[Tasks]
Components: webserver; Name: glassfishservice; Description: "Register the web server as a Windows Service."; GroupDescription: "Web Server Options";

[Run]
Tasks: glassfishservice; Components: webserver; Filename: asadmin; Parameters: "create-service MyApp"; WorkingDir: "{sd}\MyApp\bin"; StatusMsg: "Creating GlassFish service."; 
Tasks: glassfishservice; Components: webserver; Filename: net; Parameters: "start ""MyApp GlassFish Server"""; StatusMsg: "Starting Windows service."; 
; https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/automatic_starting_of_servers_in  AND   https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/how_to_make_v3_platform
Filename: SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe; WorkingDir: {src}\bin; Description: "Installs SQL Server 32-bit edition."; StatusMsg: "Installing SQL Server Express 2008..."; Components: sqlserver\sqlserver_x86; Flags: HideWizard 32bit; 
Filename: SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe; WorkingDir: {src}\bin; Description: "Installs SQL Server 64-bit edition."; StatusMsg: "Installing SQL Server Express 2008..."; Components: sqlserver\sqlserver_x64; Flags: HideWizard 64bit; 
Components: "sqlserver sqlserver\sqlserver_x64 sqlserver\sqlserver_x86"; Filename: sqlcmd; Parameters: "-S COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS -i {sd}\bin\script.sql"; Description: "Creating database."; 

[InnoIDE_PostCompile]
Name: "C:\Program Files\PowerISO\piso.exe"; Parameters: "create -o """"{#MyAppName} - v{#MyAppVersion}.iso"""" -add Release /"; Flags: CmdPrompt; 

[UninstallRun]
Tasks: glassfishservice; Components: webserver; Filename: net; Parameters: "stop ""MyApp GlassFish Server"""; StatusMsg: "Stopping Windows service."; 
Tasks: glassfishservice; Components: webserver; Filename: asadmin; Parameters: "_delete-service MyApp"; WorkingDir: "{sd}\MyApp\bin"; StatusMsg: "Destroying GlassFish service.";

[Dirs]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an InnoSetup install, check your `[Run]` section for a `postinstall` entry and remove it.
The `postinstall` is defined in the [docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) as:

> postinstall
>
> ```
> Valid only in a [Run] section. Instructs Setup to create a checkbox on the Setup Completed wizard page. The user can uncheck or
> ```
>
> check this checkbox and thereby choose whether this entry should be
>   processed or not. Previously this flag was called showcheckbox.

Another cause of a check box on the Finished page is the `isreadme` flag.  From the [docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

> isreadme
>
> File is the "README" file. Only one file in an installation can have
>   this flag. When a file has this flag, the user will asked if he/she
>   would like to view the README file after the installation has
>   completed. If Yes is chosen, Setup will open the file, using the
>   default program for the file type. For this reason, the README file
>   should always end with an extension like .txt, .wri, or .doc.
>
> Note that if Setup has to restart the user's computer (as a result of
>   installing a file with the flag restartreplace or if the AlwaysRestart
>   [Setup] section directive is yes), the user will not be given an
>   option to view the README file

Comment: I searched the whole file and couldn't find postinstall.

Comment: Ok let's say I wanted to leave this read me file option enabled. When the post install screen shows, the checkbox is labeled "View". Is there a way to set that label? I'm also getting an error about the file not existing even though I specified the .TXT file in the script relative to the setup.exe file.

Comment: The error is because of the EXTERNAL flag and the DONTCOPY flag.  By the time the "view README" process is spawned, the temp file has been removed.  If you change it to copy the file to the {app} directory, remove the DONTCOPY and EXTERNAL flags, it will work and will say "View README.TXT".   If you want to change the description, you might want to remove the ISREADME flag and add an entry in the [RUN] section with the SHELLEXEC and POSTINSTALL flags.  You can set the text by setting the DESCRIPTION parameter in that entry.